# How would you translate "how fast" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

Like in:

> It depends on **how fast** you are able to learn

This is what I tried:

> Depende de la rapidez tuyo que puedes aprender

Comment: Hi Gina, could you try to translate it yourself first? The rules of the site encourage us to let people try first and then we help them, pointing out mistakes or explaining the _why_ of something, instead of just giving solutions to them. Thanks.

Comment: Okii. 'Depiende de la rapidez tuyo que peudes aprender'. I know this is wrong tough.

Comment: fedorqui answer uses Castilian Spanish, and ustanak answer is mostly used for Latin American speakers. Both are correct and both should be understood by any native Spanish speaker person.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, to translate *how fast*, *lo rápido* is a good construction.

So I would say:

> Depende de **lo rápido** que puedas aprender

Or, something that sounds a bit better but is not that much a direct translation of the full sentence:

> Depende de **lo rápido** que aprendas

Here, *lo* works as a neutral defined article, as [DRAE says](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ESraxkH):

> 11. art. deter. n. Pondera el grado del adjetivo o el adverbio al que modifica. U. seguido de una subordinada introducida por que. *Ya sabes
>       lo lentos que son. Admiro lo bien que trabaja.*

Comment: I don't think "lo" is a pronoun there but an article. That is, sense 1 in your link wich redirects to "el", and sense 9 there.

Comment: Thinking it over, I think it's sense 11: "11. art. deter. n. Pondera el grado del adjetivo o el adverbio al que modifica. U. seguido de una subordinada introducida por *que*. *Ya sabes lo lentos que son. Admiro lo bien que trabaja.*

Comment: @Yay gracias por la corrección. Edité para reflejar lo que comentas.

Comment: Taken from the DPD: "Por su parte, *lo* suele considerarse como artículo neutro por su capacidad de sustantivar adjetivos y determinadas oraciones de relativo: *lo malo*, *lo que está mal*; para muchos lingüistas se trata, en cambio, de un pronombre." There is no consensus on the grammatical category of this word.

Answer (score 12):

*how fast* has two ways:

1. Depende de **qué tan rápido** eres capaz de aprender.
2. Depende de **cuán rápido** eres capaz de aprender.

Often, *qué tan* and *cuán* are interchangeable.